# GStreamer tutorial not working

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm working my way through the GStreamer documentation. I'm running on OSX 10.8.5 and I can initalize GStreamer using the example 4.1 code (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-init.html) from the command line with `gcc eg41.c -o eg41  -framework GStreamer -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers`

and similar for example 4.2. Now I'm wanting to work through the tutorials that come with the SDK. I've copied the whole "tutorials" folder and can compile the first one with `gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic1 -framework GStreamer -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers`

However, when I try to run the basic1 file, I get the following error message:

```
(basic1:62265): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: GstStateChangeReturn gst_element_set_state(GstElement *, GstState): assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic1:62265): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: GstBus *gst_element_get_bus(GstElement *): assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic1:62265): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: GstMessage *gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(GstBus *, GstClockTime, GstMessageType): assertion 'GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed

(basic1:62265): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: void gst_object_unref(gpointer): assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(basic1:62265): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: GstStateChangeReturn gst_element_set_state(GstElement *, GstState): assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic1:62265): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: void gst_object_unref(gpointer): assertion 'object != NULL' failed
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please include the code you have a problem with in the post, otherwise helping is just guesswork. Have you checked if there's an error returned from the call that creates the element (e.g. `gst_parse_launch()`) ?

Comment: I'm going to make a wild guess: You are following this http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735 but are using Gstreamer 1.0 (SDK docs are for 0.10). Gstreamer 1.0 renamed playbin2 into playbin so you need to change that in the example.

Comment: That was exactly it! Is there any documentation of these sorts of differences between 0.10 and 1.0? THANKS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Modifying the apparently helpful comment to an actual answer since this seems like a  common problem...)

The GStreamer SDK (and the relevant documentation) is still based on Gstreamer 0.10. The [example code](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735) in this case uses `playbin2`: if you want to try the same code with Gstreamer 1.0, you'll need to change that to `playbin` -- otherwise it looks fine.

With regards to API differences between 0.10 vs 1.0 in general, there is a [list of changes](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/appendix/porting-1-0.html?gi-language=c) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks jku! I'm now on tutorial 5 and get a compile error can't find gst/video/videooverlay - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777031/gstreamer-gst-video-videooverlay-h-file-not-found any ideas?

Comment: Is this why, perhaps, the 1.0 SDK doesn't ship with gtk folder? If so, how can I get that and install it?